# DB Migration scripts required for WSO2 Governance Registry

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

We are doing a DB Migration for WSo2 Governance Registry from 4.5.0 and migration script is not available for some specific versions at WSO2 Site hence requesting for the same for the specified versions below. Please find below the versions as we are doing a Sequential migration and kindly facilitate the script for both Oracle and MySQL

GREG versions starting from 4.5.3, 4.6.0, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0
Database: Oracle and MySQL

Comment: Did you refer the relevant documentation and stuck on a specific step or are you requiring the instructions to upgrade the WSO2 Governance Registry?

Comment: I have added an answer providing the instructions to migrate. Please check if that's what you are looking for. If not please elaborate the question more.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the instructions given in these documentations to upgrade the WSO2 Governance Registry.

[1] - [Upgrading from G-REG 4.5.3 to 4.6.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release)

[2] - [Upgrading from G-REG 4.6.0 to 5.0.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance500/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release)

[3] - [Upgrading from G-REG 5.0.0 to 5.0.1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance501/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release)

[4] - [Upgrading from G-REG 5.0.1 to 5.1.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release)

[5] - [Upgrading from G-REG 5.1.0 to 5.2.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release)

[6] - [Upgrading from G-REG 5.2.0 to 5.3.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release)

Note that from G-REG 5.0.0 onwards, it provides a migration client for the ease of upgrading.